# Update Manager tells me my system up to date but

Tags: package-management

Update Manager told me my 'system is up to date', but when I clicked 'Refresh' a list of recommended packages appeared. I presumed Linux Mint automatically updated when the system boots up; does it not? I had been surfing the web for 20 minutes before opening Update Manager so Mint had plenty of time to check for updates. Why didn't the list appear initially?

Comment: My Mint box does that at every boot, there must be a setting somewhere.

Comment: I discovered within Update Manager->Preferences->Auto-Refresh an option to change the length of time Update Manager takes to refresh the update list. It was set to 30 mins. I had thought that since hours passed between shutting the computer down and booting it up auto-refresh would instantly display the refreshed list, not wait 30 mins after booting.